# (Unity, C#) NGO Relay 404 error after attempting to join using Lobby info

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer

I'm having some issues that I can't seem to find the answer to online. I am creating a unique application where everyone is connecting to the same lobby, but instantly, without pressing anything. So what I do, is I check with the lobby service if there are any lobbies. If no, we create the lobby. If yes, we join the only lobby. And that's it, from there everyone is in the same lobby and my game would be working.

I feel like I'm doing most things decently, but the issue arises when I attempt to join the lobby. I can debug on both the host and the client, and I confirm that the relay code / server is being properly set up on the host, and I confirm that the client is receiving that exact code. All the while, the server is open on the host, and therefore the relay should stay open (right?)

So when the client attempts to join, it gets to where it would join, and returns a 404 error, which I believe means it couldn't even find the lobby. I had tried other things and gotten a few other errors, off the top of my head 409 and 402. I can't seem to find what most of them mean, because there's virtually no documentation on it. Anyways, here's the relevant code:

**Client joining runs this code

```
Debug.Log("Set current lobby to the first found lobby");
                currentLobby = foundLobbies[0];
                
                Debug.Log("Getting relay code from lobby");
                string relayJoinCodeCache = currentLobby.Data["Relay Join Code"].Value;
                
                Debug.Log("Creating join allocation from relay code. Code is " + relayJoinCodeCache + " at a length of " + relayJoinCodeCache.Length);
                
                JoinAllocation allocation;
                try
                {
                    allocation = await RelayService.Instance.JoinAllocationAsync(relayJoinCodeCache);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Relay create join code request failed");
                    throw;
                }

                Debug.Log($"client: {allocation.ConnectionData[0]} {allocation.ConnectionData[1]}");
                Debug.Log($"host: {allocation.HostConnectionData[0]} {allocation.HostConnectionData[1]}");
                Debug.Log($"client: {allocation.AllocationId}");
                
                Debug.Log("Setting relay server data from join allocation");
                NetworkManager.Singleton.GetComponent<UnityTransport>().SetRelayServerData(new RelayServerData(allocation, "wss"));
                
                Debug.Log("Starting client...");
                NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();
```

Host setting up lobby runs this code

```
Debug.Log("Didn't find lobbies, trying to create one...");
            
            Allocation allocation = await RelayService.Instance.CreateAllocationAsync(maxPlayers - 1);
            await AllocateRelayServerAndGetJoinCode(maxPlayers);
            
            var lobbyData = new Dictionary<string, DataObject>()
            {
                ["Test"] = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, "true", DataObject.IndexOptions.S1),
                ["GameMode"] = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, "ctf", DataObject.IndexOptions.S2),
                ["Skill"] = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, Random.Range(1, 51).ToString(), DataObject.IndexOptions.N1),
                ["Rank"] = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, Random.Range(1, 51).ToString()),
            };
            
            
            
            currentLobby = await LobbyService.Instance.CreateLobbyAsync(
                lobbyName: newLobbyName,
                maxPlayers: maxPlayers,
                
                options: new CreateLobbyOptions()
                {
                    Data = lobbyData,
                    IsPrivate = false,
                    Player = loggedInPlayer
                });

            Debug.Log($"Created new lobby {currentLobby.Name} ({currentLobby.Id})");
            
            
            RelayServerData relayServerData = new RelayServerData(allocation, "wss");
            NetworkManager.Singleton.GetComponent<UnityTransport>().SetRelayServerData(relayServerData);
            
            Debug.Log("Starting host...");
            NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
            
            //get the lobby and relay codes and deposit them below to global vars

            await LobbyService.Instance.UpdateLobbyAsync(currentLobby.Id, new UpdateLobbyOptions
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, DataObject>()
                {
                    ["Test"] = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, "true", DataObject.IndexOptions.S1),
                    ["GameMode"] = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, "ctf", DataObject.IndexOptions.S2),
                    ["Skill"] = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, Random.Range(1, 51).ToString(), DataObject.IndexOptions.N1),
                    ["Rank"] = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, Random.Range(1, 51).ToString()),
                    ["Lobby Join Code"] = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, currentLobby.LobbyCode, DataObject.IndexOptions.S3),
                    ["Relay Join Code"] = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, RelayJoinCode, DataObject.IndexOptions.S4)
                }
            });

            Debug.Log("Host's lobby code is " + currentLobby.LobbyCode);
            
            OnBindHost(allocation);

            StartCoroutine(HeartbeatLobbyCoroutine(currentLobby.Id, 5));
```

Thanks for any help

I tried to reorder a few things, I made plenty of debugs so I know exactly how far the code gets, and nothing seems to work

Comment: did you find your solution? im searching for the problem